# Android voice call recordings doesn't play on system

Tags: android, audio, recording

I have a small program to record all voice calls from Android phone. Recording is done fine and i am even able to playback on any android device. But the same file doesn't play on system. I have tried several player but no luck. Only Audacity complaints that the file is RAW. I have tried using Audacity to encode the file but no luck. Here is the snippet of my recording, any help is highly appreciated.

```
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setAudioChannels(2);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

Comment: Note that both AMR-NB and AMR-WB only support mono audio, so trying to specify 2 audio channels is pointless.

Comment: I tried other MONO option but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB` indicates a codec called `Adapative Multi-Rate Wideband`. This format is not very common except on mobile phones. You can get them to open up in `Audacity` if you jump through all of the right hoops. First you have to have ffmpeg installed and configured correctly for it and then when you open the file in audacity you select `FFmpeg-compatible files` for the format. However, if you want your files to be portable I think you'd be better of selecting a different codec when you record - like MPEG-4 for example.

Comment: Thanks for information. I tried AAC, AAC_ELD, HE_AAC, VORBIS. All of them are included in android SDK by default. But still no luck.

Comment: You'll have to change both the OutputFormat and the AudioEncoder. For example, `AudioEncoder.AAC` and `OutputFormat.MPEG_4` is probably your best bet if you want to be compatible with PC/Mac audio applications.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will definitely try this and let you know. What should be file extension of file with the above configuration ? .MP4 ? or .WAV?

Comment: Thanks  Micheal. AudioEncoder.AAC and OutputFormat.MPEG_4 works fine. I am able to play the recorded file on system. But size of recorded file to very large ~ 1 MB per second